# How can I allow image file upload to paperclip when the user uploads from Android?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I just noticed that the file type will be this when the user uploads file from Android's default browser.

> application/octet-stream

But this file type means various types of file so that paperclip allows users to upload almost anything :(

I was restricting the type of the file to be uploaded by this code

**models/comment.rb**

```
validates_attachment_content_type :comment_icon, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif']
```

But with this, user with Android's default browser cannot upload.

How can I enable upload from Android's default browser?